# Not seeing BLE device advertising unless set bluetoothctl transport le

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm using `bluetoothctl` 5.53 to scan for BLE advertisement. Initially, I tried `bluetoothctl scan on` but I'm not seeing the device advertising. I scanned with the nRfConnect app and was able to verify that the device is indeed advertising. Just not seeing it with the `bluetoothctl`.

After some searches, I found the following setting allows me to discover the advertising BLE device:

```
$bluetoothctl
[bluetooth]# menu scan
[bluetooth]# transport le
[bluetooth]# scan on
```

After looking through the bluez documentation, I saw this and it suggested the default `bluetoothctl` should be able to discover BLE devices:

```
string Transport (Default "auto")

                Transport parameter determines the type of
                scan.

                Possible values:
                    "auto"  - interleaved scan
                    "bredr" - BR/EDR inquiry
                    "le"    - LE scan only

                If "le" or "bredr" Transport is requested,
                and the controller doesn't support it,
                org.bluez.Error.Failed error will be returned.
                If "auto" transport is requested, scan will use
                LE, BREDR, or both, depending on what's
                currently enabled on the controller.
```

Doc here: https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/doc/adapter-api.txt#n95

However, this StackOverflow post suggests that the default filter might blocking me from seeing a lot of advertising devices: [How to use bluetoothctl like hcitool lescan to report repeated proximity beacons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36607626/how-to-use-bluetoothctl-like-hcitool-lescan-to-report-repeated-proximity-beacons)

I also ran this to clear the filter setting, but I'm still not seeing any BLE devices

```
$bluetoothctl
[bluetooth]# menu scan
[bluetooth]# clear
[bluetooth]# back
[bluetooth]# scan on
```

So my question is:

1. why am I not seeing BLE device advertising with just `bluetoothctl scan on`?
2. is there a way to set the `transport le` permanently? So that everytime I do `bluetoothctl scan on` it looks for BLE devices?

Comment: What is `ControllerMode` set to in `/etc/bluetooth/main.conf`

Comment: @ukBaz it's set to dual:
```
# Restricts all controllers to the specified transport. Default value
# is "dual", i.e. both BR/EDR and LE enabled (when supported by the HW).
# Possible values: "dual", "bredr", "le"
#ControllerMode = dual
```

Comment: Do you see different behaviour if you uncomment that line and set it to `ControllerMode = le`?

Comment: Unfortunatly I don't see any differences. First I tried to uncomment the line with the `ControllerMode` set to `dual` (since the comment suggests that the dual mode should be able to see le devices). Ran `bluetoothctl scan on`, cannot see the BLE device.

Then I tried to set the value to `le`, and run `bluetoothctl scan on`, still no luck

Comment: I saw one BLE device. Just not the one I'm advertising `[CHG] Device 5A:1D:F6:D8:FD:AA RSSI: -77
[NEW] Device 2C:41:A1:89:7A:1E LE-Bose Micro SoundLink
[CHG] Device 28:11:A5:CA:A1:0F RSSI: -69`

I can see the one I'm advertising using nRfConnect tho

Comment: Did your restart the bluetooth service between file changes? e.g. `sudo service bluetooth restart`

Comment: I tried restarting the service and scan the device again, but I'm not seeing the BLE device.
Also rebooted the laptop, and not discovering the advertisement as well. 
I'm running Ubuntu 18